# Connection to SQL Server requires TCP communication on port 50235?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have an SQL Server 2008 R2 with a database instance running on port 1433. 1433 is open for TCP and 1434 is open for UDP.

When connecting through Microsoft SQL Management Studio, our firewall detects TCP traffic at **port 50235**. Why? The SQL Server does not mention this port as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you connecting to a *named instance*?  In which case, the initial connection is to the SQL Server Browser service (**UDP 1434**) and then that dynamically allocates a port for named instances.  This port is allocated on instance startup.

See this TechNet Resource on [how the SQL Server Browser Service allocates a port for named instances](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087%28SQL.100%29.aspx).

There is a way to explicitly define a static port that a named instance will be listening on, but it appears that you are seeing a dynamically allocated port.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will operate on dynamic ports by default. Check the [SQL Server network utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189083%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) if you want to disable this.

http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/blogs/sarab/sql-server-bi/105/how-to-find-the-dynamic-port-reserved-by-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess, your firewall detects the traffic coming back from server:1433 to client:50235? This is absolutely normal behaviour for just about every network client application ever.

[Read up on ephemeral ports.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port)

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you may already know this but you can try doing a telnet to the sql server machine on port 1433:

```
telnet <hostname> 1433
```

If you get a blank screen (open connection) then your service is running on that port and there's no firewall in the way. If that's not working try:

```
telnet <hostname> 50235
```

If that works, then as the previous answer suggests you're configured for dynamic ports instead of 1433 (dynamic is the default for Express edition). You can change that in:

*SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > TCP/IP (Right Click > Properties > IP Addresses.*

In the IPAll section set TCP Dynamic Ports to blank (not 0) and enter 1433 for the TCP port)

Hope that helps.